# Global variable for each function

Tags: python, function, global-variables, nameerror

I have lots of functions, they all edit some variable but I want each to edit the previously edited variable (by the prior function):

```
text = "a"    
def a():
        text + " hi"
        print(text)
def b():
       text + " there"
       print(text)
def main():
      a()
      b()
main()
```

^So when running main I want this to appear:

```
>>a hi
>>a hi there
```

*I've tried **global** but I can't seem get it working*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when using `global`, you still have to *re-assign a new value* to the global variable - in your case `text`. `text + " hi"` simply creates a new string and throws it away. Use `global text` and then do `text = 'text' + <string>` as well:

```
text = "a"    

def a():
    global text
    text = text + " hi"
    print(text)

def b():
    global text
    text = text + " there"
    print(text)

def main():
      a()
      b()
main()
```

The above now outputs:

```
a hi
a hi there
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Out of interest, if text ="a" was in a separate function and not outside them all, how would one call it in a different function?

Comment: You'd still use global. [Here's a simple example](https://ideone.com/f9i1M6) of what I mean @GskgskgxBczkgxlhx. Also, please don't forget to [mark my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

use `global` in order to reassign text variable

```
text = "a"    
def a():
    global text
    text += " hi"
    print(text)
def b():
    global text
    text += " there"
    print(text)
def main():
    a()
    b()
main()
```

result with

```
a hi
a hi there
```

Comment: ofcourse, sorry i'd used online repl for testing and it paste it weird